# Fatal error: Call to a member function format() using PHP function

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to convert the date in the following manner and its working fine

```
$strdate = '1st of September 2014 Mon';
contime($strdate);
```

Now, I tried to convert the date in the following manner and its not working

```
$strdate = $fetch_resdetails['coupondate'];
contime($strdate);
```

I am getting `Fatal error: Call to a member function format()`

**PHP Class:**

```
function contime($gettime) {
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("jS \of F Y D", $gettime);
        return $date->format('Ymd');      
}
```

Why does the `$strdate` works perfectly and `$fetch_resdetails['coupondate'];` doesn't work?

even when  `echo $fetch_resdetails['coupondate'];` prints as `'1st of September 2014 Mon'`;

Comment: before `return $date....` add `if ($date===false) {print_r(DateTime::getLastErrors());die();}` and provide output

Comment: Output `Array ( [warning_count] => 0 [warnings] => Array ( ) [error_count] => 1 [errors] => Array ( [0] => Data missing ) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function contime($gettime) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("jS \of F Y D", $gettime);
    return $date->format('Y-m-d');      
}
$fetch_resdetails = array( 'getdate'    => '1st of September 2014 Mon' );
$strdate = $fetch_resdetails['getdate'];
$date = contime($strdate);
print_r( $date );
```

This is working..can you check with this code..

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors",1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$strdate = '1st of September 2014 Mon';
echo contime($strdate);
$fetch_resdetails['coupondate']="1st of September 2014 Mon";

$strdate = $fetch_resdetails['coupondate'];
echo contime($strdate);

function contime($gettime) {
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("jS \of F Y D", $gettime);
        return $date->format('Ymd');      
}
```

this is working.to get your error i sent the $fetch_resdetails['coupondate'] without assigning anything and got the same error.so before sending $fetch_resdetails['coupondate'] check if it hase some value or not.